# Service has stopped because of reboot of SQL Server example rebooting

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, delphi, service

I work with Delphi 2010 and SQL Server 2012. Components for database is sdac.

I have a service working with database and it has several threads. In them it executes different requests to database. Every of these threads had a connection timeout and command timeout, and separate `tmsconnection` of course. And one time a sample of SQL Server itself was rebooted by the admin.

Operations in main thread had coped with this situation without problem. One of the other threads have written error in its connection and it was worked out, but stopped hang itself just after, I think in the beginning of next iteration. Other threads which had connection only initially worked out this situation without any problems.

Tell me please, does it mean during every connection to database in a secondary threads, I run the risk of hanging if the server would be rebooted during that time, and I can do nothing to protect against that?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking here. But you should realize that sql server 2012 is no longer supported. You should consider upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: If SQLServer is rebooted, you should not get hangs, you should get errors, which you can catch and handle as needed.

Comment: Review **your** code. Seen similar issues with code that reconnects automatically but doesn't restore things to the same state as before the error - like having a different database or schema set vs when the connection is first established.

Comment: I asked here how to avoid stopping in situation i have described before and make sure my service works without stopping whatever happens with our sql server example. Thank you for your feedback. As i understood from it this behavior ist very common. I will try to repeat this situation artificially in the time if low activity on our database and probably will to my classes of threads feature of controlling is it alive. And if it isn't i will mark old object as disabled and start a new one. This situation is really rare and i can be not afraid of stockpiling of such  objects for sure